# PingFederate: SP-Initiated single logout 'SLO' with opentoken adapter

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, pingfederate

When doing an sp-initiated SLO while configuring an opentoken adapter for the IdP. I don't get to go to the adapter configured SLO-Service, what actually happens is that I go to the logout endpoint of the SP and that's it, I am not redirected to the SLO Service in the Adapter.

Noting that if I do an Idp-Initiated SLO fine in other scenarios however in this specific SP I am disabling the idp-initiating SLO. should I send any extra information to the idp? is this a normal behavior?

Comment: I'd take a look at this TRT if you haven't already. Sounds like something isn't quite right. https://www.pingidentity.com/support/training-center/training-video.cfm/trt-single-log-out?id=2415947630001 - Or feel free to open a Support Case with us [Note: I work for Ping] -- Ian

Comment: In the video it states that the user has to go to the opentoken logout service, also the documentation in the page http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/NETIK251/IdP+Single+Logout+%28SLO%29 states that. However when you try to implement with SP-Initiated SLO (where usually your endpoint is /idp/SLO.saml2), what happens is that no redirection to the SP page occurs !! if it is SP-Initiated, IdP initiated works fine since at the end the redirection to the SLO logout service, while in SP_initiated I expected that the logout will occur in the beginning of the SLO but it doesn't

Comment: What URL are you using to initiate the SLO? You need to ensure you request the Application Endpoint first (/sp/startSLO.ping) which will redirect you to the appropriate adapter(s) Logout URL IIRC.

Comment: As I understood startSLO.ping is where you start an Idp-initiated SLO, if you disable IdP-initiated SLO you will receive an error ! I started at the SLO endpoint /idp/SLO.saml2

Comment: I want to make sure I understand the question:
You are the IdP, and you are using PingFed (version?). You are saying that IdP-init SLO works fine, but SP-init does not? What is the endpoint that you have provided the SP for SLO? Do you get any errors in your logs?

Answer (score 0):

There are Application Endpoints for the IDP and the SP Initiated events. There are also Protocol Endpoints for where the actual protocol messages are received/sent. You are using the Protocol Endpoint which is not correct. For SP-Init SLO you *must* initiate the process by calling the /sp/startSLO.ping Application Endpoint. here is the documentation on the [SP Application Endpoints](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF71/SP+Services).

Comment: Ian I am not using ping identity as an sp but as IdP ! If it is an IdP an sp-initiated SLO will go to endpoint /idp/SLO.saml2

Comment: That is not what your original question states. You state you are performing SP-Init SLO and configuring the SP Adapter. I would strongly suggest opening a Support Case and having our team help you walk thru your configuration in detail at this point.

Comment: Ian did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, basically here are the things you need to check:

1. Make sure you have a value specified in SP Default URLs. To do that:

   a. Access Admin console using https://localhost:9999/pingfederate/app

   b. Then follow this step: SP Configuration > Application Integration Settings > Default URLs

   c. Add default URL under this line: "Provide the default URL you would like to send the user to when Single Logout (SLO) has succeeded."
2. When you are going to initiate the SLO, add TargetResource query string with the value of your redirect URL.

   This is how I implemented it in .NET:

   Response.Redirect(<pingfederate_server_url> & "/sp/startSLO.ping?TargetResource=" & "http://<redirect_url>/", True)
3. Make sure you have set the correct SLO Service URLs in your IdP Connection.

   Sample value of SLO Service URL: https://<idp_DNS>:9031/idp/SLO.saml2